# Execute an action based on how many times an element appears in a list

Tags: python

I have a list :

```
CASE 1 :  group_member = ['MEU1', 'MEU1','MEU2', 'MEU1','MEU1','MEU2','MEU1','MEU2','MEU1','MEU3']
CASE 2 :  group_member = ['MEU1','MEU2','MEU3','None','None']
CASE 3 :  group_member = ['MEU1','MEU2','MEU3','MEU1','CEU1']
```

What I'm trying to do is insert a value in a table in sql if 70% of the list has the same value or send mail to some users if the values is below 70%.

For the list I have above it will be the first case because EU1 value is bigger than 70%.

I tried something like this :

```
from collections import Counter 

freqDict = Counter(group_member) 
size = len(group_member) 
if len(group_member) > 0 :
   for (key,val) in freqDict.items(): 
     if (val >= (7*size/10)):
        print(">= than70%")
        insert_into_table(group)

     elif (val <(7*size/10)) :
        print("under 70%")
        send_mail_notification(group)
```

The problem with this is that it will check for each combinations of key and value and that would mean even if one value is >= 70% it will still enter the `elif` and send mail multiple times for the same group which is unacceptable but i didn't found a solution for this yet.

How can I avoid this cases? For the list above it should only insert the value in the table and move on to the next list, for the second list it should only send a mail notification only one time because there is no element >=70%.

I need to implement the following cases:

1. If >=70% is the same value (ex MEU1 in CASE1) then insert into a table.
2. IF >=70% is in the same unit (M) but not the same tribe, so in CASE 3 because 4 of 5 elements have M they belong to the same Unit --> send notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should check if there's at least one item with a value greater or equal than 70, then send mail if there's no such value. This means you should check if you should send a mail after you go through the list.

```
from collections import Counter 

freqDict = Counter(group_member) 
size = len(group_member) 
foundBigVal = False

if len(group_member) > 0 :
   for (key,val) in freqDict.items(): 
     if (val >= (7*size/10)):
        print(">= than70%")
        insert_into_table(group)
        foundBigVal = True
        break #no need to check the list further since only one can have %70 percent
if foundBigVal:
#if there's a value greater than %70 in the list, we would enter this part
   print("under 70%")
   send_mail_notification(group)
```

I put the if outside the loop in order to call `send_mail_notification` once but check each element inside the list.

Comment: I don't fully understand your solution ,is that second if outside for ? , shouldn't it be inside? ,also i just updated the post with more details to be easier to understand.

Comment: `foundBigVal` is not necessary. You can put an `else` on a `for`

Comment: @rzss275 As the comment states, the code will break out at the first occurrence of >= 70%

Comment: @astrochun Yes i know it will break then , the problem for me is the second case i explained above .

Comment: @rzss275 I'm trying to understand the question better, I think this version would solve the unedited version of your problem, but if there's an additional check before sending an email, such as checking the first letter of the items as well, I have to change the solution. I believe me forgetting to set foundBigVal inside the if statement led to a misunderstanding.

Comment: @Monata yes that works for the unedited version , thank you ,i will try myself to get a solution for the new version , thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
a = ['EU1', 'EU1','EU2', 'EU1','EU1','EU2','EU1','EU2','EU1','EU3']
max_percentage = Counter(a).most_common(1)[0][1]/len(a)*100
```

`most_common(1)[0]` returns a tuple in the form of `(most_common_element, its_count)`. We just extract the count and divide it by the total length of the list to find the percentage.

Although it seems that the percentage of `EU1` in the above list is 60%, not 70, as you mentioned.

Comment: Hello ,thanks for you comment , i added more details in my post ,and i don't see how your solution would work in my case .